# How to prevent root from running git pull?

Tags: git, permissions, githooks, git-pull, ownership

Have need to prevent root from updating a git (working) directory.  Reasoning includes but not limited to: preventing undersired file-system ownership changes.

None of the git hooks seem to *prevent* a fetch/merge/pull before it happens, similar to pre-commit hook.  Or at least, nothing I see here (or in man page): 
http://www.analysisandsolutions.com/code/git-hooks-summary-cheat-sheet.htm

Thoughts?

Comment: *“prevent root […]”* – I don’t think that’s possible.

Comment: Why? What is the actual problem you're trying to avoid? If you're trying to prevent files in your repository from being owned by root, don't pull while you're logged in as root.

Comment: @meagar Already doing this.  Alas, in a team environment where many people have root/sudo access.  Want to specifically deter people from logging in as root and inadvertantly changing things they shouldn't. Sometimes people forget old habits (we used to require root/sudo privs for updates, but no longer), login as root, and do stuff they shouldn't.

Comment: @poke one could theoretically put a 'if [ "$(id -u)" == "0" ]; then exit 1' check in a pre-fetch hook... if a pre-fetch hook existed.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167406/how-do-you-deal-with-file-ownership-in-git#3167457

Comment: I think the answer is to start punishing people for careless use of root access. First step would be to revoke root access...

Comment: @meagar Yeah, that's reasonable.  Additionally: think we've fixed to overall prob by 1) a post-checkout chmod/chown cmd script (which we had) that 2) sets not only the group but the user ownership (which we previously didn't) and 3) making said user/group ownership suitably restrictive.  Adding #2 and #3 appears (as of yet unconfirmed) to obviate need for "root disabled" solution.  But still would be nice if such solution and/or a "pre-fetch" commit hook existed, for future reference or employment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way I saw this not resolved but at least "mitigated" was through a **wrapper for the git command**:

All git commands go through this wrapper which proceeds if the user id is not root.

Answer (score 12):

Change `/root/.bashrc` to add a new directory to the beginning of the `PATH`. Add a shell script there called `git` that tests `$1` to be one of a few read-only commands (show/status/log/rev-list etc) and calls `/usr/bin/git "$@"` if the command is acceptable. This will prevent anybody on your team from accidentally running `git pull` as root. If you are worried about them doing it deliberately, you have bigger problems...

Comment: Better yet, have the command just print an error message like `Please do not run git as root`.

Comment: In my case it's the manager of my department who keeps doing 'sudo su' whenever he doesn't have permission to do something. Then he does a git pull and screws up my files. I just want an error message for any git command which says "Never run git commands as root! Stop messing up my file permissions!"