# GIT stop copying owner and group permissios

Tags: linux, git

Is there any way to say to GIT to stop copying file group and owner settings? My situation is as followed:

I am developing on home server where I need to use my users permissions (not root) in order to develop in Eclipse IDE (Eclipse crying if files are in root owner and group as it cannot work with them).
Once I am done, I am using GIT to synchronize with remote server which is running on Red Hat and file/folders groups and owners are server specific. However when I will synchronize it will copy my home servers permissions as well and apache on remote server throwing errors as it cannot read files so I need to reset it myself after every commit on new/changed files.

Any thoughts how to change my workflow?

P.S: I am using Linux/Debian on home server

Comment: Do you use git as root (i.e. `sudo git`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the answer here: [How do you deal with file ownership in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167406/how-do-you-deal-with-file-ownership-in-git)

You're not doing anything wrong, this is just basic git behavior. You can change the permissions locally to what they need to be on the server and do a new commit. Or you can create a script to fix all of the ownerships/permissions on the server when you do your sync.

If you are using a git push to push the changes to your server via a git repository on the server, you can create a post-receive hook to call this script.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

One other thing did occur to me. A lot of Linux distros set the default umask as 0077 or 0007. Since I'm the only one using my laptop, I changed mine to 0002 since it just makes many things easier (plus my home directory is still 700). So all files I create will be rwxrwxr-x. Changing your umask would keep you from needing to think about setting the permissions later.

Comment: You're right on the money with the umask - since git doesn't store the owner or the permissions, adjusting your umask is the way to handle this problem...!

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think I will just do hook and run chown and chgrp commands straight after pull. Edit: I realized its not git problem at all probably as the files after pull are set up by the user who is running git commands at the machine.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer to my question after a while and though I will answer just for the record.

User/group ownership is not shared (and therefore stored) through the repository. Only numeric file permissions are transferred (e.g. 644).

The file which is updated/created will adapt user and group ownership from the current user that is running Git commands.